# how to properly use GCD to do long process on back thread and UI process/update on maion thread

Tags: iphone, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

i am working on this piece of code as this blocks main thread reported by time profiler.

```
OrderModule *module = [OrderModule sharedModule];
for(Modifier *modifier in modifierLists)
{
    int merge = [module getModifierMergeOption:modifier.mModifierId productId:product.mProductId];//long process database interaction

    for(ModifierItem *mod_product in modifier.activeModifiers)
    {
        NSString *modifierProductName = mod_product.productName;
        if (merge == 1) {

            modifierProductName = [modifierProductName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - ",product.mProductName] withString:@""];
        }

        numberOfModifiers++;
        UILabel *modifierNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        //            [modifierNameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        modifierNameLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        modifierNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        modifierNameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        modifierNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [modifierNameLabel setFont:DEFAULT_FONT(DEFAULT_FONTSIZE_MODIFIERNAME)];
        modifierNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:125.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:131.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        //            modifierNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 35);
        modifierNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 120, 35);

        modifierNameLabel.text = modifierProductName;
        [orderDetailRow addSubview:modifierNameLabel];


        UILabel *modifierAmount = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [modifierAmount setFont:DEFAULT_FONT(DEFAULT_FONTSIZE_MODIFIERNAME)];
        modifierAmount.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:125.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:131.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        //            modifierAmount.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(modifierNameLabel.frame)+30, y, 100, 35);
        modifierAmount.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(modifierNameLabel.frame)+6, y, 100, 35);

        [orderDetailRow addSubview:modifierAmount];

        //                modifiersCount++;

        amountPrice=amountPrice+([mod_product.mExtraCost floatValue]*count);
        [modifierAmount setText:[Utils currencyWithSymbol:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",(([mod_product.mExtraCost floatValue]*count)+ 0.00001)]]];//simple manipulation

        if ([mod_product.mExtraCost floatValue]<=0) { //3.0 changes
            [modifierAmount setHidden:YES];
        }

        y = y + 25;

    }
    numberOfModifiers++;

}

[self setUpActiveModifierWithX:x andy:y Row:orderDetailRow andModifierList:modifierLists andProduct:product];
```

i have tried with this way:

```
-(void)setUpModifierWithX:(float)x andy:(float)y Row:(OrderDetailRow *)orderDetailRow andModifierList:(NSMutableArray *)modifierLists andProduct:(Product *)product
{
    OrderModule *module = [OrderModule sharedModule];
    float __block Y = y;
    for(Modifier *modifier in modifierLists)
    {
        int __block merge;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

             merge= [module getModifierMergeOption:modifier.mModifierId productId:product.mProductId];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {
                for(ModifierItem *mod_product in modifier.activeModifiers)
                {
                    NSString *modifierProductName = mod_product.productName;
                    if (merge == 1) {

                        modifierProductName = [modifierProductName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - ",product.mProductName] withString:@""];
                    }

                    numberOfModifiers++;
                    UILabel *modifierNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
                    //            [modifierNameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                    modifierNameLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
                    modifierNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                    modifierNameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
                    modifierNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                    [modifierNameLabel setFont:DEFAULT_FONT(DEFAULT_FONTSIZE_MODIFIERNAME)];
                    modifierNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:125.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:131.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
                    //            modifierNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 35);
                    modifierNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 120, 35);

                    modifierNameLabel.text = modifierProductName;
                    [orderDetailRow addSubview:modifierNameLabel];


                    UILabel *modifierAmount = [[UILabel alloc] init];
                    [modifierAmount setFont:DEFAULT_FONT(DEFAULT_FONTSIZE_MODIFIERNAME)];
                    modifierAmount.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:125.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:131.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
                    //            modifierAmount.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(modifierNameLabel.frame)+30, y, 100, 35);
                    modifierAmount.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(modifierNameLabel.frame)+6, y, 100, 35);

                    [orderDetailRow addSubview:modifierAmount];

                    //                modifiersCount++;

                    amountPrice=amountPrice+([mod_product.mExtraCost floatValue]*count);
                    [modifierAmount setText:[Utils currencyWithSymbol:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",(([mod_product.mExtraCost floatValue]*count)+ 0.00001)]]];

                    if ([mod_product.mExtraCost floatValue]<=0) { //3.0 changes
                        [modifierAmount setHidden:YES];
                    }

                    Y = Y + 25;

                }
                numberOfModifiers++;
            });
        });



    }

    [self setUpActiveModifierWithX:x andy:y Row:orderDetailRow andModifierList:modifierLists andProduct:product];

}
```

but setUpActiveModifierWithX:x is called before the  for loop ends execution, how do i call setUpActiveModifierWithX:x method after that for loop.

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I'd step back from what you are doing, and learn how to use a TableViewController or CollectionViewController.

You seem to be creating an awful lot of subviews, which is an expensive operation. Table views and collection views avoid this by reusing the same views over and over again, just displaying different values. Instead of expensive views you use much cheaper cells. You also automatically only handle things that are actually visible, so if you have thousand items, only the dozen on your screen will take CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is putting it after the last statement in the block executed on the main thread:

**EDIT**

This below won't work, and unfortunately, there is no "easy fix" without using a third partly library. I leave the answer here for demonstrating how things quickly get more complex with asynchronous problems.

```
-(void)setUpModifierWithX:(float)x andy:(float)y Row:(OrderDetailRow *)orderDetailRow andModifierList:(NSMutableArray *)modifierLists andProduct:(Product *)product
{
    OrderModule *module = [OrderModule sharedModule];
    float __block Y = y;
    for(Modifier *modifier in modifierLists)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            int merge= [module getModifierMergeOption:modifier.mModifierId productId:product.mProductId];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {
                for(ModifierItem *mod_product in modifier.activeModifiers)
                {
                   ...
                }
                numberOfModifiers++;


               [self setUpActiveModifierWithX:x andy:y Row:orderDetailRow andModifierList:modifierLists andProduct:product];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: then it will be executed n number of time see above your code lies in for loop ,,thanx

Comment: @Alok You are right, this doesn't work. I propose another solution, which however does seem to be that easy... added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this seemingly easy task isn't actually that easy. I couldn't find a solution that's easier than the following, *without* resorting to a *third party library* which makes such tasks much easier (I'll propose a solution using an utility library later).

So, here is an approach which uses a *recursive block*.

**WARNING**

> Recursive blocks, are tricky - and I wouldn't recommend to use them unless you know why and how you apply this technique.

The code snippet shows the principal approach, but your original problem needs to be adjusted.

Your method

```
-(void)setUpModifierWithX:(float)x andy:(float)y Row:(OrderDetailRow *)orderDetailRow andModifierList:(NSMutableArray *)modifierLists andProduct:(Product *)product
```

becomes now an *asynchronous* method:

```
-(void) foo
{
    NSArray* array = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];  // your input array, e.g. "modifierLists"

    NSMutableArray* marray = [array mutableCopy]; // we need a mutable array here

    typedef void (^completion_t)(id result);
    typedef void (^block_t)(NSMutableArray*, completion_t);

    // setting up block variable suitable for using that block recursively:
    __block __weak block_t weak_block;
    block_t block;
    weak_block = block  = ^(NSMutableArray*array, completion_t completion) {

        // Check the termination condition for the "loop"
        if ([array count] == 0) {
            if (completion) {
                completion(@"Finished");
            }
            return;
        }
        id item = array[0]; 
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            // process "item" on a secondary thread (private queue):
            int merge = [item characterAtIndex:0]; //[module getModifierMergeOption:modifier.mModifierId productId:product.mProductId];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // On the main thread, setup the UIKit objects:
                NSLog(@"%d", merge);
                /*
                for(ModifierItem *mod_product in modifier.activeModifiers)
                {
                    ...
                }
                numberOfModifiers++;
                */

                // Continue the loop:
                weak_block(array, completion);  //looks scary!
            });
        });
    };


    // Start the loop:

    block(marray, ^(id result){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
            //[self setUpActiveModifierWithX:x andy:y Row:orderDetailRow andModifierList:modifierLists andProduct:product];
        });
    });
}
```

Regarding recursive blocks, see this question [ARC behavior within a recursive block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622754/arc-behavior-within-a-recursive-block/19622925#19622925)  and this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626441/465677